# Handling null values with wso2 CEP

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi, wso2-cep

I want to update event table (RDBMS) using additional condition that one column in that is not null. Table name is MSISDNProfileDB and it's in oracle db.

```
from incomingStream#window.length(1)
select  correlation_MSISDN as MSISDN, 
        INTERACTION_DT as INTERACTION_DT
update MSISDNProfileDB
on MSISDNProfileDB.MSISDN == MSISDN
and not(MSISDNProfileDB.column1 is null);
```

it validates the code, but does not update INTERACTION_DT. For testing purposes, I changed it to check if the column is null, and manually remove data from column1.

```
from incomingStream#window.length(1)
select  correlation_MSISDN as MSISDN, 
        INTERACTION_DT as INTERACTION_DT
update MSISDNProfileDB
on MSISDNProfileDB.MSISDN == MSISDN
and MSISDNProfileDB.column1 is null;
```

...and it still doesnt work. But when I change column value to 1 and do this:

```
from incomingStream#window.length(1)
select  correlation_MSISDN as MSISDN, 
        INTERACTION_DT as INTERACTION_DT
update MSISDNProfileDB
on MSISDNProfileDB.MSISDN == MSISDN
and MSISDNProfileDB.column1 == '1';
```

it works! So, conclusion is that cep has problem with null values from oracle db. Does anyone knows how are null values handled?

Kind Regards,
Stefan

Comment: Hi, are you getting any exception similar to `org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.ExecutionPlanRuntimeException: Error while updating events in database,You have an error in your SQL syntax;...`, when you send an event?

Comment: Hi Granier, when I try to update using this line ...and MSISDNProfileDB.column1 is null... in carbon log there is error: "Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a similar problem with MySQL. The issue seems to be in the way CEP parse Siddhi query into SQL. I did a quick [fix](https://github.com/grainier/siddhi/commit/bbde8484dca10e9d876c7b7aeebee879ce2f40c0) for that, and it worked for my scenario. It should work in your case too, but haven't tested with Oracle though. To use the fix (assuming you are using [CEP 4.2.0](http://wso2.com/products/complex-event-processor/));

1. Delete `siddhi-extension-event-table_3.1.2.jar` from `<cep>/repository/components/plugins/` directory.
2. Add [compiled jar](https://mega.nz/#!cxVWFCaR!9LLgFPwKg_Yst9b5HNTDuFS2ChM8lKag_LWdnER_MyU) to `<cep>/repository/components/lib/` diectory.
3. Use following query;

   ```
   from incomingStream
   select  
       correlation_MSISDN as MSISDN, 
       INTERACTION_DT as INTERACTION_DT
   update MSISDNProfileDB
   on MSISDNProfileDB.MSISDN == MSISDN and not (MSISDNProfileDB.column1 is null);
   ```

Comment: Thank you Grainier for your support! I'm working with CEP 4.1.0, can I also compile this jar on 4.1.0 version?

Comment: CEP 4.2.0 uses Siddhi 3.1.2, CEP 4.1.0 uses Siddhi 3.0.5. So you might need to apply the changes to [v3.0.5 tag](https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/tree/v3.0.5). Here's a [patched jar for v3.0.5](https://mega.nz/#!Qx8zRbTD!-_JySYc0KHT-pmRWGy31GX0rbF_hHIjv-eAs_SLwloE). Try it and see.

Comment: Now everything works. Thank you very much! Kind regards, Stefan

Comment: Hi, me again :) Can you please also check how publisher is behaving for same problem. When I try to insert empty string to rdbms from execution plan it works fine(column value in oracle is null), but when i try this using publisher it's not. I guess you resolved this for execution plan and not for publisher also? Kind Regards,Stefan

Comment: Hi @StStojanovic, could you please create a [JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CEP) for the above, and inform it on WSO2 public mailing list (dev@wso2.org). Also, please consider accepting, or voting up the answer if it was helpful :)